# Merging two azure blobs to single blob using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

In azure container there were multiple blobs having same name with different extensions (eg: file_01.txt,file_02.txt,file_03.txt).
Can anyone please tell How to concatenate these 3 file contents to sinlge file content (eg:- All_files.txt) & place it in same conatiner using azure powershell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement , we have created a PowerShell script to download the blob from you storage account to local & will merge the blobs and upload back to different container.

Here is the PowerShell script:

```
$storagecontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName '<storageaccoutName>' -StorageAccountKey '<storageAccountKey>'

$storagelist= Get-AzStorageBlob -Container '<containerName>' -Context $storagecontext

$storagearray =$storagelist

foreach($storagelist in $storagearray)
{
    
  Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container testblob -Blob $storagelist.Name -Context $storagecontext -Destination C:\Users\Downloads\

    $name = $storagelist.Name
    Get-Content C:\Users\Downloads\$($name) | Add-Content C:\Users\Downloads\Allfile.txt
   
}
az storage blob upload --container-name '<newUplodingContainerName>'  -f 'C:\Users\Downloads\Allfile.txt' -n 'allfile.txt' --account-name '<storageAccountName>' --account-key '<storageAccountKey>'
```

Here is the reference output of the above PowerShell script :

[image]

Comment: Thank you VenkateshDodda. This logic is working fine.